# How to start Composer blockchain business network to Hyperledger Fabric (multiple organizations)?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

Deploying a Hyperledger Composer blockchain business network to Hyperledger Fabric (multiple organizations) is working fine until i need to close my computer and try to connect again

I followed this tutorial=https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.19/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org

For the first time the command "composer-rest-server" worked fine but after there is an error and i am unable to connect again 
That is the error:

To restart the REST server using the same options, issue the following command:

`composer-rest-server -c alice@trade-network -n never -d n -w true`

> Discovering types from business network definition ...
>   Connection fails: Error: Error trying to ping. Error: No peers available to query. last error was Error: Failed to connect before the deadline
>   It will be retried for the next request.
>   Exception: Error: Error trying to ping. Error: No peers available to query. last error was Error: Failed to connect before the deadline
>   Error: Error trying to ping. Error: No peers available to query. last error was Error: Failed to connect before the deadline
>       at _checkRuntimeVersions.then.catch

Comment: Are your containers running?

Comment: I restarted containers and works. Thank you